# Flash Message (Rails v.4.1.1) Curly Brackets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash

I'm creating a blog on rails. Everytime a post is created on the **new** page I want to be back at the **index** page and see a flash message saying "You post was saved". On the layout I have the following:

```
<body>

<%= flash.each do |key, value| %>
    <p><%= value %></p>
<% end %>


<%= yield %>

</body>
```

The problem is that I have now on every page (index, new, etc.) curly brackets on the top and I don't know why. Also, instead of just having a message "Your post was saved.". It also appears the following: "{"notice"=>"Your post was saved."}". This is the code for the message hold on the controller (posts_controller.rb):

```
def create
        @post = Post.new(post_params)

        if @post.save
            redirect_to posts_path
            flash[:notice] = "Your post was saved."
        else
            render "new"
        end
end
```

I'm beginning with Rails, thanks for the help.

Comment: remove the `=` in `<%= flash.each.... %>` Should just be `<% flash.each.....%>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**See update below for explanation**

remove the = in <%= flash.each.... %> Should just be <% flash.each.....%>

```
<% flash.each do |key, value| %>
  <p><%= value %></p>
<% end %>
```

To keep it simple, when you want your ruby code to render something onto the page, use `<%= %>`, **ex**: to show the current time you would use `<%= Time.now %>`. For other things like settings variables in your view without text rendering on the page, use `<% %>`.

For example, say I want to assign a variable equal to the current time so I can use it below in the view, I would use `<% time = Time.now %>` then I can show that time on the page with `<%= time %>`.

```
<% time = Time.now %>

<p>The current time is <%= time %>.</p>
```

Comment: Since the asker is a beginner in Rails, can you explain why he has to use `<% %>` and not `<%= %>`?

Comment: To keep it simple, when you want your ruby code to render something onto the page, use `<%= %>`, *ex:* to show the current time you would use `<%= Time.now %>`. For other things like settings variables in your view *without* text rendering on the page, use `<% %>`. for example, say I want to assign a variable equal to the current time so I can use it below in the view, I would use `<% time = Time.now %>` then I can show that time on the page with `<%= time %>`.

Comment: Thanks a million!! Really appreciate it. Thanks for the explanation also, it works perfect now ;)

Comment: @Justin: the comment about the angle brackets is very good - can you move it to your answer? If you have additional detail it is best to update the post and then add a quick 'see my update' comment. (The reason for this is that comments are intended to be ephemeral, and they are not necessarily presented with the answer text in the API).